# Selenium TestNG - click on webtable element found by what it contains

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

New to Selenium-TestNG-Java

I'm trying to find an number on a webtable and click it, as I want to be able to pick the correct number on the list. Or get the location of said number so I can select that row by clicking the first element.

[This is the one I need to "pinpoint"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mBoI.png)

But the only thing I have is the Xpath ( `//*[@id="multisujetoSociosTable"]/tbody/tr/td[5]/b` ) and inside it is the number I need "`< b >33210266801< / b >`"

Any idea or tip?
Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Please post relevant HTML of the table??

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using an xpath using text() to check the containing text?

```
//*[@id="multisujetoSociosTable"]/tbody//tr/td[text()='33210266801']
```

you could also combine with contains:

```
//*[@id="multisujetoSociosTable"]/tbody//tr/td[contains(text(),'33210266801')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned above 'get.text()' should to the trick